# How to decode string on c++

Tags: c++

How to decode string in c++.
for example utf8 to cp1251 or koi8-r to utf8

Comment: You may start describing your environment.

Comment: There may be method in the library "boost" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ has no native support for performing such conversions. You could look at [ICU](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/) library.

> ICU is a mature, widely used set of C/C++ and Java libraries providing Unicode and Globalization support for software applications. ICU is widely portable and gives applications the same results on all platforms and between C/C++ and Java software.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`libiconv`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) or [`icu`](http://icu-project.org/).